# How can I install a specific version of golint for use globally?

Tags: go, version-control, package-managers, go-modules, golint

I'm trying to create a docker image for use in a build pipeline that has various tools pre-installed for building and testing go projects. One tool we need is `golint` but I'm struggling to see how to install a specific version of it. The reason I want to lock down the version is to avoid accidental / unwanted / unintended breakages at a later date.

For a start, looking [here](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/lint@v0.0.0-20200302205851-738671d3881b/golint?tab=versions) the versions are not exactly in an easy-to-type format.

Also when I try to use the following command

```
go get -u golang.org/x/lint/golint@v0.0.0-20181217174547-8f45f776aaf1
```

I get an error

```
go: cannot use path@version syntax in GOPATH mode
```

Googling has so far yielded very few relevant results...

Is what I'm trying to do possible? Many thanks!

Comment: You can check out the repo at whatever tag/branch/commit you want and run `go install` in it.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian I'm going to take that advice. It seems the simplest way to get what I need done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to be in [go module](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules) mode to get code of a specific version, since in addition to downloading the code, the version is recorded in the go module file.

The easiest way to do this would be to create an empty directory, run `go mod init`, which will create a `go.mod` file.

Then, you can run `go get golang.org/x/lint/golint@v0.0.0-20181217174547-8f45f776aaf1`, which will add `golint` at that version to your go.mod file. You can then run `go install golang.org/x/lint/golint` from within that directory, which will install `golint` at the version specified into your `$GOBIN` directory (which defaults to `$GOPATH/bin`).